# How to outsource \hypersetup to an external file?

Tags: hyperref, packages, external-files, package-options

I use the [hyperref](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/) package and defined [custom settings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization) as follows:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=OliveGreen     % color of external links
}
```

I [saw here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430025/356895) that I can somehow put these settings into an external file to slim down the preamble. I created a `hyperref.sty` and moved the `\hypersetup{}` part in there. I noticed that it is considered in the compilation process, however, it fails.

**Question:**

What is the proper way to externalize the options for the *hyperref* package?

Comment: If you load the package `xcolor` there is no need to load `color`. You can externalize the setup in an extra file which can be include by `input`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just place the hypersetup command into `myfile.tex` then

```
\input{myfile}
```

don't create a file called hyperref.sty or you will prevent the original loading.

Answer (score 7):

### `hyperref.cfg`

If the file `hyperref.cfg` exists, then package `hyperref` loads this file right before it processes its options. Therefore you can put many option settings via `\hypersetup` in this file. Options for PDF informations should be loaded after the package `hyperref` is loaded. In `hyperref.cfg` this can be done via:

```
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor={me}, ...}%
}
```

An extended example for `hyperref.cfg`:

```
\hypersetup{%
  bookmarks,%
  pdfencoding=auto,%
  colorlinks,%
  ...
}%
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \hypersetup{%
    pdfauthor={...},%
    ...
  }%
  \RequirePackage{bookmark}%
}%
```

### `myhyperref.cfg`

In your original approach you cannot use `hyperref.sty` as file name, because this name is already used by the package itself. But via `\input` a different file name can be loaded:

```
\input{myhyperref.cfg}
```

But after `hyperref` is loaded, some options cannot be changed anymore.

### Package `myhyperref`

A third approach is to write a small package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myhyperref}[2012/09/07 v1.0]

\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[
  bookmarks,
  colorlinks,
  pdfencoding=auto,
]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  open,
}
\hypersetup{
  linkcolor=red,
  % ...
  pdfauthor={me},
  % ...
}

\endinput
```

Then the package is loaded via `\usepackage` in the main document:

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\usepackage{myhyperref}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I know which options have to be loaded **before** or **after** the package hyperref is loaded?

Comment: `hyperref` warns if an option is used too late.

Comment: When I use your *myhyperref* example I end up with this error: `Option clash for package hyperref.` at line 10. I load the package as the last one.