# Load PDF metadata from an external file

Tags: hyperref

I see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70600/how-to-outsource-hypersetup-to-an-external-file) that it's nice to put the entire `\hypersetup` command in an external .tex file. In my case, only a snippet is required, which has been generated by an external program and will change frequently, say, a build number. But this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\input{buildno.txt}}  % other info omitted

\begin{document}
Thanks
\end{document}
```

The generated PDF will have a subject "buildno.txt" rather than the text file's content. Is there a convenience way to load such information without scripting the entire `\hypersetup` command in the external file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the external file to define the subject as a command, then input the file and use the command; for example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{buildnodef.txt}
\def\buildno{version 6}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\input{buildnodef.txt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\buildno}  % other info omitted

\begin{document}
Thanks
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could read the contents of the file to a command, which may then be used. Using, for example, the `catchfile` package:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{buildno.txt}
version 7
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\buildno}{buildno.txt}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\buildno}  % other info omitted

\begin{document}
Thanks
\end{document}
```